# Overfitting on implemented Dense-Net architecture

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification

I have been playing with different architectures and see how they would perform on the quick draw dataset. Even though the accuracy is significantly higher, I can't reduce overfitting no matter what I do. Even with data augmentations, the model is still overfitting. I suspect it might be because of the data itself, but maybe I am wrong.

Here is my code to get the data and load the data:

```
import quickdraw as qd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import tensorflow.keras.activations as activations
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
import math
%load_ext tensorboard
```

Some parameters

```
n_classes = 100
input_shape = (128, 128, 1)
img_size = (128, 128)
max_drawings = 1200
batch_size = 256
dataset_dir = "/content/dataset"
```

Load data code

```
def load_image_classes(name, max_dws=1200, recognized=True):
  directory = pathlib.Path("dataset/" + name)

  if not directory.exists():
    directory.mkdir(parents=True)

  images = qd.QuickDrawDataGroup(name, max_drawings=max_dws, recognized=True)

  for img in images.drawings:
    filepath = directory.as_posix() + "/" + str(img.key_id) + ".png"
    img.get_image(stroke_width=3).resize(img_size).save(filepath)

for name in qd.QuickDrawData().drawing_names[:n_classes]:
  load_image_classes(name=name, max_dws=max_drawings, recognized=True)
```

Load data

```
train_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    dataset_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=42,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    image_size=img_size,
    batch_size=batch_size
)

test_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    dataset_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=42,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    image_size=img_size,
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```

Dense net implementation

```
def dense_conv(x, filter, kernel=1, s=1, p='same'):
  x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
  x = layers.Conv2D(filter, kernel, strides=s, padding=p)(x)
  return x

def dense_block(x, filter, repetition):
  for i in range(repetition):
      y = dense_conv(x, filter=filter*4, kernel=1)
      y = dense_conv(y, filter=filter, kernel=3)
      x = layers.concatenate([y, x])

  return x

def transition_layer(x):
  x = dense_conv(x, tf.keras.backend.int_shape(x)[-1] //2, kernel=1)
  x = layers.AveragePooling2D(2, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  return x

def construct_densenet121(filter):
  input_im = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
  x = layers.RandomRotation(0.2)(input_im)
  x = layers.RandomFlip('horizontal_and_vertical')(x)

  # Stage 1
  x = layers.Conv2D(64, 7, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  x = layers.MaxPool2D(3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)

  # Stage 2
  for repetition in [6, 12, 24, 16]:
    x = dense_block(x=x, filter=filter, repetition=repetition)
    x = transition_layer(x)

  # Stage 3: Classification
  x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

  model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_im, outputs=x, name='DenseNet121')
  return model

densenet121 = construct_densenet121(32)
densenet121.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    optimizer='adam',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 14

tf.random.set_seed(42)

logdir = os.path.join("logs", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)
densenet121.fit(train_data, validation_data=test_data, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

This is the training process:

````
Epoch 1/14
625/625 [==============================] - 687s 908ms/step - loss: 2.4456 - accuracy: 0.3724 - val_loss: 15.6159 - val_accuracy: 0.0206

Epoch 2/14
625/625 [==============================] - 571s 912ms/step - loss: 1.3466 - accuracy: 0.6168 - val_loss: 29.3167 - val_accuracy: 0.0134

Epoch 3/14
625/625 [==============================] - 563s 900ms/step - loss: 1.0751 - accuracy: 0.6876 - val_loss: 15.2280 - val_accuracy: 0.0292

Epoch 4/14
625/625 [==============================] - 563s 900ms/step - loss: 0.9426 - accuracy: 0.7224 - val_loss: 17.8689 - val_accuracy: 0.0376
```
````